# Telerik Calendar: disable selection

Tags: calendar, telerik

I have telerik controls on my page. I am making a vacation calendar using Telerik's radcalendar.
I want to disable weekend dates so that employees cannot select weekend dates for leave approval. 
Can someone please help?

PS: I have multi-select enabled on my calendar control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik has great documentation. Looking on their site/forum would probably produce an answer faster than asking a question at Stack Overflow. Here's a few links to get you going:

[Disabling Calendar Days](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/calendar/disabling-calendar-days.aspx)

[Calendar / Special Days and templates](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/functionality/specialdays/defaultcs.aspx)